# A better word than 'cathouse' for an outside shelter for 1 cat

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, british-english

Most of us who have *gardens** **and** are fond of nature and animals have outside shelters for them...

- birdhouse
- dog house
- green house
- ***cat house?***

*['Cathouse'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cathouse)* seems *off* to many Americans because of the usage  as a slang term for brothel, and will probably draw a snicker or two..

I participate on Pets.SE, and can find [only 1 reference to 'cat-house'](https://pets.stackexchange.com/search?q=cat%20house%20)

"Cattery" has been suggested on Wikipedia and [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-shelter-of-a-cat-called), but that sounds like a kennel for cats. In other words, similar to an 'aviary'.

'Shelter' sounds like a place for adoption of strays.

Is there a less-suggestive word for the house of a single cat, that works like  'doghouse'?

SWR:My cat lay comfortably dry inside her ______, watching  the rain fall on the patio below her.

---

*My usage of *garden* here is more the European or Latin-American idea. *Garden* for Americans often evokes the image of tidy rows of vegetables ripening on the vine and close to hand of the home cook, or  a bed of seasonal flowers.
By way of contrast, for the rest of the English-speaking  world , it  usually indicates trees, flowers, bushes, grassy patches, etc.

The perfect environment for birds, rodents, and various  creepy-crawlies...

In other words, *paradise* for a cat.

Comment: In context, I think "cat shelter" works just fine; there's no chance the reader would think the cat is waiting to be adopted.

Comment: For us non-Americans, what on earth is wrong with "cat house"?

Comment: @AndrewLeach - I think they use it to mean 'brothel'.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Check the [dictionary definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cathouse).

Comment: Use kitty: Kitty house. :) There is also (mostly inside but it could be outside, too) Kitty condo. By the way, it's cat house, the other is puteria.

Comment: @CanadianYankee No. That information should be in the question, which should not assume anything is obvious.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I apologize for the opacity of the Q...I made the assumption it was a well-known usage. The Q has been edited.

Comment: It doesn't fit your context, but you might be interested in the term "catio" (cat + patio). It's an enclosure with a roof, often attached to a house, so that an indoor cat can enjoy the outdoors safely and comfortably. Here's a random site with pictures (they also use the term "cat house"): https://www.thecattopia.com/catio-images/

Comment: @ColleenV Yes, those designs are incredible...if I were only 10 years younger I would build something like that for my kitty. We are in the beginning of our rainy season here, and my kitty often comes in at the afternoon wet, and complaining when she cannot get to her to her favorite perch on the retaining wall where she can bask  in the sun. For some reason she thinks I control the weather!

Comment: @Andrew Leach. In hiker slang, "cathole" is the term used for the area one digs while backcountry to poop in. Whether that relates to "cathouse" I don't know

Comment: @Cascabel Poor kitty. Honestly, if humans didn't know how to hunt tuna and other tasty canned goods, I don't know why the cats would put up with us :P I guess we're sometimes suitable cat furniture. We had plans to build a small catio for [our older cat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpjyG.jpg) so he could watch the hummingbirds, but we didn't get it done before he got sick and we had to euthanize him. Have you seen the cat TV videos on YouTube? Sometimes they can make up for gloomy weather. Our cat enjoyed this one of mice running around: https://youtu.be/6pbreU5ChmA

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm a cat owner, but my first thought of "cat house" would not be a brothel even though I'm an American. Where I'm from those are whorehouses.

Comment: @ColleenV Oh My Dog...I'm sorry for your troubles. That could not have been an easy decision. My cocker right now is suffering from some kind of hip or butt thing, and cannot jump into the truck the way she used to...been to the vet twice, but he says she is getting on, and to expect that. I'm not so sure...// in my country, cats are a difficult prospect; no matter how high the wall (10 ft.) they always get over it. She's spayed, but cats have their own nocturnal routines...and I swear to dog I think she is importing mouses. –

Comment: We're going through something similar with our oldest dog (it's been a rough couple of months). She's been partially paralyzed from a back injury for 10 years or so and recently took a tumble off her ramp when she was heading outside. You might ask your vet about gabapentin - our dog has been on it a daily dose of it for a while. It's not expensive (in the US at least) and it seemed to help her. I could see if my husband still has the plans for the little set of stairs he built for her so she could get up on the couch. Sheesh, we really do spoil our pets I guess.

Comment: @ColleenV  As the chief of staff to many cats over 35 years,  I don't regard it as spoiling them, but as just doing my job!  I wish all cats had people like you and me.  Sadly, so many do not.

Comment: @StuW I think it's more likely to be related to what cats do when they poop in litter boxes.

Comment: All the pet supply places use the term "cat house." As an American, I don't think this is likely to draw snickers. We never bothered to come up with a euphemism for "chicken breast" so...

Comment: Gallinaceous boob? [couldn't resist]

Comment: If dog shed, why not cat shed?

Comment: @GArthurBrown You'd be wrong. [It's getting less common but you'd draw snickers](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cathouse&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) and even teach an entire new generation of kids around the neighborhood about it. That said, **just reclaim the term and call it a cathouse anyway**.

Comment: @lly I'm not sure the Ngram provides evidence for my being wrong or who would and would not snicker. The name "Dick" is still common enough that it implies people don't mind calling themselves a name for the male genitals. Of course people make puns on this kind of stuff occasionally. But many words with risqué usages still remain entirely common. We didn't rename [boobies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booby) or [tits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tit_(bird)) and no one has any trouble dealing with their usage in ornithology books.

Comment: A house for cats is not common like a dog house. Dog house is a long established thing and it is popular in media also. Cats mostly don't prefer/need a house-like structure like dogs. For stray cats, it is usually mentioned as "winter cat shelter", "feral cat shelter". They wouldn't need it in warm/summer months. Also, a doghouse-like structure is not useful for stray cats in winter. People usually build small rectangular spaces with smaller openings to keep inside warm. Other than that, pet stores/shopping sites still use the term "cat house" along with some other terms.

Answer (score 9):

I find plenty of hits on Amazon and other sites for **Cat kennel**.

https://www.thepetexpress.co.uk/outdoor-cat-kennels-shelters/

https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=Cat+Kennel&ref=nb_sb_noss_2

Comment: Yes, but the doghouses on that site are also called kennel/shelter...I am asking for a word similar to 'doghouse'..'.kennel' is an umbrella term, as is 'shelter'.

Comment: @Cascabel - Hmm, given your sentence as context, in what way do you think “kennel” could be misconstrued and what nuance of does “doghouse” capture that it lacks?

Comment: I have two cat kennels in my garden. My neighbour has one in her garden. That's what we call them (BrE). (Up-voted +1.)

Comment: If 'kennel' is an umbrella term, what is the 'house' part of dog house/doghouse, birdhouse etc. I'd say 'cat kennel' is becoming as much a single term (lexeme) as dog house/doghouse; open compounds are merely spelling variants of closed ones by this stage.

Comment: Lemme think on it...

Answer (score 6):

Cat hut—has a roof, at least. Or close it—cathut? *Cathut!* Sounds like a hairball...

Or cattyshack—has walls...and balls, maybe snacks.

A cat folly has a fountain...and a chaise, of course.

A cat retreat has towers, plural, and all the amenities, but everybody knows that.

---

Per suggestion in comments below:

> My cat lay comfortably dry inside her *catio,* watching the rain fall
> on the patio…

Now that's really cute, no doubt.

Comment: Only words endorsable by reasonable references fit ELU's format (the U standing for [standard] usage). DIY candidates are off-topic. Are these suggestions to be found in dictionaries?

Comment: Cattyshack is my favorite--but then, I do have a twisted sense of humor.

Comment: Oh My Dog ...I wanna check this one...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Most outdoor cats live in cat huts per the 2020 Felinnial Census. I blame the economy.

Comment: Google seems to have quite a few hits for a *catio*, but I think that's more than the bungalow alone.

Comment: @tchrist, yes, *catio* normally refers to an enclosed outdoor run, for an otherwise indoor cat (e.g., of course, a patio with a high fence and wire mesh rig)

Comment: _de nada_ ... I will check another answer off, but I did want to reward this one.

Answer (score 4):

I withdraw my earlier suggestion of catloo because I agree it sounds like a litter box, and moreover would not be immediately obvious to the vast majority of readers.  So, herewith is:

**Cat cabin or Kitty Cabin**

This was mentioned in a comment by @**KannE** under the **cat hut** answer, above, but they did not develop it into an answer.

> According to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cabin) a cabin is a small one-story dwelling
> usually of simple construction.

See also [Sponsor a Cat Cabin](https://www.cats.org.uk/boston/support-us/sponsor-a-cat-cabin) on
*Cats Protection*, the site for a British organization. A US organization, [Alley Cat Allies](https://www.google.com/search?q=vaccine&oq=&aqs=chrome.0.69i59i450l8.1277561003j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) has a similar construction, called a KatKabin which can be seen on this link.

The enclosures in a **catio** may have multiple shelves rising to the top of the enclosure, but a catio is not the same as a cat house, being at least partially exposed to the elements.  Houses for felines and canines are almost always one story high and of simple construction.  If more elaborate than a cabin, they are cat manses or cat mansions. Although I have never seen one, I am sure a cat mansion exists, probably in the LA region.

**PS**: From personal experience, I can vouch for the fact that people-cabins can have lofts, and so not all cabins are necessarily on one level.

Comment: Along the same lines, the place where we boarded our cat during our move referred to the kennels as [kitty condos](https://comfycatzinc.com/) although that seems more likely to refer to indoor multi-level climbing furniture if you search Google images. The Boston PD [called the house they made for the stray that adopted them a "kitty condo"](https://bpdnews.com/news/2017/2/11/swat-cat-gets-a-new-kitty-condo-team-mascot-moves-into-new-home-at-swat-base) too though, so maybe it would work in context. I'm also coming across "cat cottage" a lot.

Comment: @ColleenV  The problem I have with kitty condo as housing for the cat or cats of an individual or an individual family is that a condo is one unit in association with many others.  Thus, the kennel where you temporarily placed your cat has kitty condos, but your own cat house for your own cat(s) is not a cat condo, even if your own abode is a condo.   As for the Boston PD nomenclature, the police have more sense than we do, and went with a servicable name rather than agonizing over it.  :}

Comment: @KannE  Purr!  for the bounty!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest **den**. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/den) gives

> **den**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> A wild mammal's hidden home; a lair.
> A room or hideout where a person can go to relax or be private.

Comment: You can find a 'cat den' on shopping sites.

Comment: Den is possible, but these days seems to more often refer to what's called a "man cave".

Comment: A big cat uses a den, so it seems appropriate for a domestic one too, and vendors agree.

Comment: Fair enough, if it's clear from the context that you're talking about a cat not a husband.

Comment: @StuartF as in "Tiddles is resting in the den?" I don't think any of the words shelter, kennel, house, den, cave are unique to a cat, and a cattery is a temporary home for a number of cats.

Comment: @WeatherVane But “Tiddles is resting in *his* den”, disambiguates.

Comment: And the Japanese have catteries in eateries. Or at least tea houses. Ha ha.

Comment: _Den_ may be the best choice, IMHO, since lions have dens, and all cats believe they are lions despite any evidence to the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

**[Hutch](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hutch)**

> a pen or coop for an animal

The term is most familiar for rabbits as a rabbit hutch, but there are commercial sellers and [hobbyists](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/sallybroughton5/cat-hutches/) who use the [term](https://www.wayfair.com/keyword.php?keyword=outdoor%20cat%20hutch) for their [offerings](https://www.etsy.com/market/cat_hutch) for cats.

Comment: A hutch, though, is for confining an animal, rather than being a pleasure-dome.

Comment: @WeatherVane Consider the [Playboy bunny hutch](https://variety.com/2013/dirt/real-estalker/hop-on-over-to-the-playboy-bunny-hutch-1201235516/)

Comment: @Cascabel I am unconvinced that "a heavy duty Valley Girl" isn't some kind of restraint... or is that the pre-bunny?

Comment: ... _de acuerdo_ @WeatherVane

Comment: Hutches are for rabbits, not for cats.

Answer (score 1):

[**Pet house for my cat**](https://www.hercampus.com/school/fsu/diy-i-made-pet-house-my-cat) returns a surprising number of results from Google. So, if you are reluctant to go with the perfectly well documented *cat house* then call it a *pet house* and if need be, clarify it is *for a cat.*

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like my earlier idea, how about *[Catcave](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22catcave%22%20%20&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiP5bHHj53xAhUX-BoKHWKoCpoQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=%22catcave%22%20%20&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIECCMQJzIECCMQJzIGCAAQChAYUKGKAlihigJg24sCaABwAHgAgAFhiAFhkgEBMZgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=W3DKYM_LD5fwa-LQqtAJ&bih=393&biw=887&client=ubuntu&hs=DXg)*.

some of them are suitable for outdoor use.

Answer (score 0):

*My cat lay comfortably dry inside her pawpen, watching the rain fall on the patio below her.*

*meowww*

Answer (score 0):

[Mu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_and_the_Art_of_Motorcycle_Maintenance). If you aren't going to follow the Yanks' ideas on what you consider a garden, there's no reason at all you need to worry about their Puritan snickering or tut-tutting over what they themselves call the things. The (presumably) largest source of these things on Earth has a specific product category for what you're talking about and it's called [**cat houses & condos**](https://www.amazon.com/cat-houses-cat-condos/b?node=2975246011) on its American platform. (The UK version leans towards indoor cat furniture and apparently doesn't do brisk enough trade in outdoor shelters to justify breaking it out as a separate product line.)

[Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cathouse%2Ccat+house%2Ccat-house%2Ccat+condo%2Ccatcondo&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) shows the usual orthography is **cathouse** in published works, but [Google Trends](http://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=US&q=cathouse,cat%20house,cat%20condo,catcondo) shows that people online have started chasing the marketers whose SEO is chasing them, preferring **cat house** by a wide margin.

Yeah, it's still suggestive but ignore the naysayers and—with a space, rammed together, or with a toffee-nosed hyphen—just say it loud and say it proud. It's already well on the way to being reclaimed, since everything else that might replace it is just silly.

Answer (score 0):

I propose taking CollenV's suggestion a step further and  blending *cat cottage* into **cattage**.